# Storing text with name in sequence

Tags: rapidminer

I am using RapidMiner 5 GUI and i want to store all the value of an attribute in different text file. But if i am using any write utility like write or write document it is either overwriting the data or giving an error.

I want to store all the value in different files with a sequence or something attached to it.

Is there any way?

Comment: What did you try? Can you provide us with some code?

Answer (score 0):

With the Loop Attributes operator you can loop with the attributes and with the Generate Macro operator you can create from the macro as attribute name a file name you prefer.